# Methods of preventing content falling under a fixed header?

Tags: html, css

I find that when I create a fixed header I use padding to move the content that has fallen below it back into view. I was wondering is there a method of creating the fixed header and keeping the content that proceeds it in the DOM all viewable without using padding/margin?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tWT6X/1

Kyle

Answer (score 0):

The only other way would be to add all content into a div and position it in a absolute position under the menu

Comment: thanks for the reply, fixing the other content will defeat the purpose of having a fixed header? i want to be able to scroll the content, fixing it will prevent me from doing that.

Comment: yea i changed it to be "absolute", as that would put it under the menu initially and when page is scrolled it will be moved under the menu.

Comment: adding absolute position wont fix this either since il still need to use the top value to pull the hidden content into view

Comment: why would that be a problem? is your menu dynamically changing in height?